# Expo Audio.Recording Cannot read property 'uri' of undefined

Tags: react-native, expo

I'm trying to start a new recording in Expo react native but for some odd reason the app crashes.
The code i written is pretty much copy paste from the official expo docs.

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from 'react';
import { Audio } from 'expo-av';
import PitchFinder from "pitchfinder";
import { StyleSheet, Text, View, Button } from 'react-native';

const Tuner = () => {
    const pitchFinder = new PitchFinder.YIN();
    const start = async () => {
        const recording = new Audio.Recording();
        console.log(recording)
        await recording.prepareToRecordAsync(Audio.RECORDING_OPTIONS_PRESET_HIGH_QUALITY);
        await recording.startAsync();
        const audio_stream = recording.getURI();
        console.log(audio_stream);
        await recording.stopAndUnloadAsync();
    }
    return (
        <View>
            <Button title="Start recording" onPress={() => start()} />
        </View>
    )
};

export default Tuner;
```

The app crashes at `await recording.prepareToRecordAsync(Audio.RECORDING_OPTIONS_PRESET_HIGH_QUALITY);`
with the error

> Unhandled Rejection (TypeError): Cannot read property 'uri' of undefined

Answer (score 0):

please check Expo documentation again
check permission

https://docs.expo.io/versions/latest/sdk/audio/

try with

```
  const recording = new Audio.Recording();
    try {
      await recording.prepareToRecordAsync(Audio.RECORDING_OPTIONS_PRESET_HIGH_QUALITY);
      await recording.startAsync();
      // You are now recording!
    } catch (error) {
      // An error occurred!
    }
```

Comment: i did check for permissions and i do have them.